# How to reload a view in angular. Google maps API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

My problem is that when I load the screen with the google map, the maps doesn't show up. first after a refresh. What it my mistake or how can i prevent this?

```
    .controller('LocationsCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

      $scope.ini = function() {

      var map;
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      function initialize() {

          var mapProp = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.4550, -3.3833),
              zoom: 7,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };

          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);

          $.getJSON("https://onepicture.ch/locations.php", function(json1) {

          $.each(json1.stores, function (key, data) {

              var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: latLng,
                  title: data.title,
                  map: map
                  // icon: icon,

              });

              var details = "<b>" + data.title + "<b><br> " +data.address + "<br> " + data.city + "<br>";

              bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, details);

              });

          });

  }

  function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, strDescription) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
          infowindow.setContent(strDescription);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


    }
})
```

Markup:

```
<ion-view ng-init="ini()">
  <ion-header-bar class="banner-top ext-box" align-title="left">
    <div class="int-box2"><h2 id="s_back1">MAP</h2></div>
  </ion-header-bar>
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true" class="has-header has-footer" scroll="false" >


  <div style="height:100%; width:100%;">
         <div id="map"></div>
    </div>



</ion-content>
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-bottom" align-title="left">
  <ul>
    <a href="#/home" nav-transition="none"><li><img src="img/home.png" class="img-left" alt=""></li></a>
    <a href="#/list" nav-transition="none"><li><img src="img/list.png" class="img-left"alt=""></li></a>
    <a href="#/map" nav-transition="none"><li><img src="img/map_de.png" class="img-left"alt=""></li></a>
    <a href="#/info" nav-transition="none"><li><img src="img/info.png" class="img-left"alt=""></li></a>
    <a href="#/tapsi" nav-transition="none"><li><img src="img/tapsy.png" class="img-left"alt=""></li></a>
  </ul>
</ion-footer-bar>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to parent container, the map div size needs to be *explicitly* specified as well:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

CSS

```
#map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5AW1JNpFOwExvT193THM?p=preview)